# Overriding HashCode

Tags: java, equals, hashset

I have a class which is a Set and I override .equals() to check if the sets are equal element-wise. How do I override HashCode since from what I've seen there is some interdependence between the two

```
public class ASet{
Set g=new Set();


public boolean equals(Object s1)
{
    Set S= (Set)s1;
    for(Object o : S.getcontents())
    {
        for(Object r : g.getcontents())
        {
            if(!o.equals(r))
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
}

 public int hashCode() {
       ?????????
 }
```

Comment: Unless you want to put this Set into another HasSet or HashMap, you won't need to override hashCode.

Comment: why do you wrap Set ?

Comment: @TwilightSun.I won't. Thats good to know! If I did how would I override it anw?

Comment: Your code does not really make sense. Firstly -- since `ASet` does not implement `Set`, your `equals` method should never return `true` when given a `Set`. Secondly -- your `equals` method should not be casting its argument without checking its runtime type, because there's no expectation that it will only be called with arguments of a certain type. Thirdly -- `Set.equals()` is already defined to perform element-wise comparison (and `Set.hashCode()` is defined in a way that's compatible with that) -- so there's no reason to write the logic yourself. Fourthly -- `new Set()` is a compile error.

Comment: BTW, I don't think your equals is correct. It will always return false if the either set contains more than 1 element.

Comment: @TwilightSun: Whenever you override `equals()`, you should override `hashCode()`.

Comment: Your equals method is requiring all elements of one set to be equal to all elements of another.  Unless `ASet` is representing an equivalence class, then there's no reason to do that.  If pair-wise equivalence is what you want, you should just rely on `Set.equals` to be implemented properly since `Set` iteration order is not specified.

Comment: Ignoring the implementation problems raised by other commenters, the rules for implementing hashCode are clearly defined in [the javadocs for Object](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html).  In this case, if two ASets have identical getcontents then they should return the same hashCode().  Since you're unlikely to ever have a hashed set of ASets (because you won't be using this code again), then just `return 1;` and your hashCode() will be valid.

Comment: @ruakh Oh, nice you pointing that out for me.

Comment: If I use the default .equals() of a Set implementation like TreeSet, what about if I have 2 different ASet Instances which contain objects (with the same field values) as elements. Will they be considered equal when comparing their elements?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, let's fix your `equals` implementation, because it is incorrect: rather than comparing elements for equality pairwise, your code checks each element of the first set against each element of the second set. So the only case when the two sets would be considered equal under this scheme is when both sets contain exactly one element, and the elements they contain are the same.

You should make two iterators, and loop them together *in a single loop*. Now you can compare elements returned by the first iterator to elements returned by the second iterator, and return `false` if they are not the same.

Now let's do the hash code: theoretically, you could simply add up the individual hash codes of your elements, and that would be a valid implementation of `hashCode()`:

```
public int hashCode() {
    int res = 0;
    for(Object r : g.getcontents()) {
        res += r.hashCode();
    }
    return res;
}
```

However, this is not the best hash code you could make, because two sets with different ordering would have the same hash code. A better approach is to multiply the previous value by a prime number (31 is a common example) before adding the next hash code to it, like this:

```
public int hashCode() {
    int res = 0;
    for(Object r : g.getcontents()) {
        res = 31 * res + r.hashCode();
    }
    return res;
}
```

Finally, a little note about collections and their hash codes: the main purpose of overriding hash code is so that you could use your object as a key in a hash-based collection (hash set or hash map). However, you should be extremely careful using mutable objects, such as sets and lists, as keys in maps or sets, because mutating the key that has been placed into the container already will jeopardize the structural integrity of your hash-based container.

Comment: he isn't implementing Set actually, he is just wrapping it up, why does he need to rewrite equals()

Comment: If I use the default .equals() of a Set implementation like TreeSet, what about if I have 2 different ASet Instances which contain objects (with the same field values) as elements. Will they be considered equal when comparing their elements?

Comment: @JigarJoshi The only reason one may want to do it is as an exercise. Perhaps the plan is to add more members besides a `Set`, or to implement his own set.

Comment: @user3236409 This implementation requires have identical elements, and also enumerate these elements in the same order. If you would like to make it order-insensitive, you may need to use an additional set object. However, this would make your `equals` method extremely expensive - much more expensive than you want your `equals` methods to be.

Comment: what do you mean by identical? like the same instances?.I mean that if I compare element wise elements of a TreeSet which are objects but different instances but with all field values the same and identical in terms of code.

Comment: @user3236409 By "identical" I mean that the elements need to compare as equal to each other using their own overrides of the `equals` method. They do not necessarily need to be the same instances (although if they are same instances that would certainly be sufficient).

Comment: Thank you very much for your answers! I would definitely up if I had enough rep.